# Como enviar nomes de um loop php para outro input usando JS

Tags: php, javascript

Como passar dados para outro input que não seja o id? exemplo nome do o value não o id.

```js
function passar(id){ 
    var valorA = document.getElementById(id); 
    var nome = document.getElementById("nome"); 
    nome.value = valorA.value; 
};
```

```html
<?php
         $sql_lista = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM login LIMIT 0, 2"); 
    //aqui fazemos a contagem para exibição se caso ouver dados(quantidade)
   $sql_contar = mysql_num_rows($sql_lista);
      ?>

  <?php
     while($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($sql_lista)){ ?>    

<?php echo $resultado['usuario'];?>
 
    <form>

<input 
    TYPE="text" 
    SIZE="3" 
    name="valorA" 
    id="valorA_<?=$resultado['lo_id'] ?>" 
    value="<?php echo $resultado['usuario'];?>" 
/>
 
<button type="button" onclick="passar(<?=$resultado['usuario']?>);"> passar valores </button>

   
 </form>
        
  <?php
  //fechamos o while
   } 
  ?>
 Nome:<input type="text" id="nome" size="10"/>
```

Comment: qual o valor que deseja passar?

Comment: tipo o seguinte eu quero passar id e o nome do usuário os dois separados tem como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faço o seguinte:

```
//Aqui você precisa passar o ID do seu campo
function passar(id){ 

    //Note que o ID do seu campo é composto por 'valorA_' + ID do usuario
    var id_campo = 'valorA_'+ id
    var valorA = document.getElementById(id_campo);

    var nome = document.getElementById("nome"); 

    nome.value = valorA.value; 
};
```

Há uma segunda opção que é passar tbm o nome por parâmetro da função:

```
<button type="button" onclick="passar(<?=$resultado['lo_id']?>,'<?= $resultado['usuario'] ?>');"> passar valores </button>
```

Porém perceba que na sua função `passar()`, você já pega o valor do campo valorA_.

Segue exemplo do código funcionando:

```
<script>
function passar(id){ 
    var valorA = document.getElementById('valorA_'+id); 
    var nome = document.getElementById("nome"); 
    nome.value = valorA.value; 
};
</script>
<?php
//Esse array é apenas para substitui sua consulta no banco nesse exemplo.
$resultado = array();
$resultado['lo_id'] = 1;
$resultado['usuario'] = 'John Doe';

?>
<form>
    <input TYPE="text" SIZE="15" name="valorA" id="valorA_<?=$resultado['lo_id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $resultado['usuario'];?>" />

    <button type="button" onclick="passar(<?=$resultado['lo_id']?>);"> passar valores </button>

</form>

 Nome:<input type="text" id="nome" size="10"/>
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: ai meu bhroter valew pela dica precisa da ideia percebi que o id ficou com uma placa certo, essa era a ideia de como fazer cara me ajudou muito estou adiantando meu tcc, e aproveitando para aprender mais. Obrigado

Comment: sabe porque não consigo fazer um select dentro do value do input chamando uma variavel que é o id da linha? <input 
    TYPE="text" 
    SIZE="3" 
    name="valorA" 
    id="valorA_<?=$resultado['via_id'] ?>" 
    value="<?php 
 
   $id_t= $resultado['via_id'];
$sql_listaB = mysql_query("select format(sum(ar_valor ), 2) as valort  from adiantamento_rel where adiantamento_depo_id_ad='$id_t'; ");    
  $resulB = mysql_fetch_array($sql_listaB);
  $valort = $resulB ['valort'];
  echo $valort;
 
 ?>" 
/>

Comment: @gezer rapaz, faz esse select fora do input, teu código vai ficar mais compreensível. Dê uma olhada na minha resposta na sua outra pergunta, veja se te atende.

Comment: @gezer veja a resposta editada, coloquei um trecho de código funcionando a passagem do nome.

Comment: fiz as alterações testei varias vezes e mais uma vez me ajudou kkk mudei para o que eu queria que é mais complexo rs e sim realmente o select no banco tinha que ser fora mesmo fiz um inner join de outra tabela para calcular um determinado valor.

Comment: Opa... que bom que consigui ajudar novamente!